# Is it possible to create variables in R using user input that can call other variables?

Tags: r

I am attempting to write an R script that utilizes user input in order to make it more universally applicable. The issue I'm running into is getting R to use variables created from user input within the script. As an example: say I have a variable named dir that specifies a certain subdirectory name. I want to prompt the user to input the desired subdirectory and then use that input in setwd("~/…/…/dir") to set working directory to that subdirectory. My current script is as follows:

```
seqdir <- readline(prompt = "Enter Sanger Seq Date: ")
setwd("~/hpchome/SangerSeq/seqdir")
```

where the user input specifies a subdirectory of SangerSeq. However, using this script results in a literal interpretation of seqdir as the name of a subdirectory that does not exist. is there any way for me to specify that I want to use the saved identity of "seqdir"?

Comment: `setwd(file.path("~/hpchome/SangerSeq", seqdir))`

Comment: Yup that did it! Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: As a more general alternative, assuming your final argument is always a string,  you can call `paste0(your_base_string, user_input_string, sep ='', collapse='')`